# Core Data Concurrency

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I would like to get some suggestion for making core data operation concurrent in my project. My project is running since two years, so that it has many implementations which can be optimized based on the availability of new features in `objectiveC`. Mainly, I am looking for optimizing `CoreData` operation.

Currently most of the data operations are done using main managed object context. Recently, I have implemented a new feature to download a big set of data and inserting in to database using core data after login. This was supposed to be execute in parallel with other operations in the application. Now I realized that the code written for core data is executing in the main thread, because the UI of application is blocking during the `coredata` operation. So I referred many blogs and came to know that there are two strategies in which core data concurrency can be achieved, Notifications with the help of multiple contexts and parent/child managed object contexts.

I tried the parent/child strategy as Apple is not preferring the other strategy. But I am getting random crashes with the exception “Collection was mutated while being enumerated” on `executeFetchRequest`. This exception starts happening after implementing the parent/child strategy. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , i know there are not so many blogs that describe efficient use of core data in project but luckily i found one... which points to your problem properly... check here-> https://medium.com/soundwave-stories/core-data-cffe22efe716#.3wcpw1ijo

also your exception is occurring because you are updating your database while it is being used somewhere to remove this exception you can do this like:

if you are fetching data in array or dictionary then do change statement like this

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [[coreDataDectionary] mutableCopy];
```

Now perform any operation on this array or dictionary which you fetch from database, it wont show any exception.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use completionBlock into your code. [here](http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-blocks-tutorial/) is tutorial and explanation.
It will allow you to not freeze your UI application even if your download is not finished.
the execution of the code will continue even if the code inside the block isn't finished yet. There will be a callback action inside the block when the download will be over.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL), ^{
    // DATA PROCESSING 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // UPDATE UI
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Core Data stack to minimize UI locks when importing large datasets:

1. One main thread MOC with its own PSC.
2. One background MOC with its own PSC.
3. Merge changes into main thread MOC on background MOC's save notifications.

Yes, you can – and should – use two independent PSCs (`NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`) pointing to the same .sqlite file. It will reduce overall locking time to just `SQLite` locks, avoiding PSC-level locks, so overall UI locking time will be [SQLite write lock] + [main thread MOC read].

You can use background MOC with `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` within a background thread or even better within an `NSOperation` – I found it very convenient to process data and feed it to Core Data on the same thread.

Import in batches. Choose batch size empirically. Reset the background MOC after each save.

When processing really large datasets, with hundreds of thousands of objects, do not use `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` with main thread MOC on every save. It is slow and eventually will consume all of the available memory. Reload your FRCs instead.

And about "Collection was mutated while being enumerated". To-many relationships in Core Data are mutable sets, so you have to make a copy, or better sort them into `NSArray`s before iterating.